# Search and Replace a string t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Everyone I am trying to write a query to replace all occurrences of a string at the end.
I have some noise words(104 to be exact) that need to be removed from the string if they appear at the end.

Two noise words for example are --Company, LLC

Here are some examples and expected output:

```
American Company, LLC --Expected output --American (both noise words should be removed)
American LLC,LLC --Expected output -- American
American Company American Company-- American Company American (one noise word occurs in between other words, so it should not be removed)
```

currently I have this query:

```
DECLARE @NEWSTRING VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @NEWSTRINGlength nvarchar(max)

SET @NEWSTRING = 'American Company American Company Company, LLC  LLC' ; 

SET @NEWSTRINGlength = len(@newstring)
SELECT @NEWSTRINGlength

CREATE TABLE #item (item Nvarchar(250) null)

INSERT INTO #item

SELECT 'Company' as item
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'LLC' as item

DECLARE @unwantedCharecters  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!, ]%'

WHILE PATINDEX( @unwantedCharecters, @NEWSTRING ) > 0
SELECT @NEWSTRING = ltrim(rtrim(Replace(REPLACE( @NEWSTRING, SUBSTRING( @NEWSTRING, PATINDEX( @unwantedCharecters, @NEWSTRING ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')))

SELECT @NEWSTRING = substring(rtrim(@NEWSTRING), 1, len(@newstring) - len(ITEM)) FROM #item WHERE  rtrim(@NEWSTRING) LIKE '%' + ITEM
```

Each occurrence of the noise word should be removed, unless they appear in between other words.

Comment: Don't manipulate strings in SQL, do it in your data access layer or presentation layer, say in C#, etc.

Comment: @abatishchev he doesnt seem to suggest that he has an app outside of sql server, maybe this is a cleanup job?

Comment: actually it is code snippet, the name comes in as input to a stored procedure..

Comment: it is past cleanup that was gone wrong..so i am trying to write a stored procedure, the code is used in many places, so i thought stored procedure is the best way to go.

Comment: Are the expected output examples correct? If the first one should not be "American Company," please explain why? The rest seems to be simple "remove the last word", but not this one.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm that you want to implement to arrive at the expected output? If you can't explain it, it's hard for us to help.

Comment: Further to abatishchev's recommendation, is using a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function an option? [How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: according to the business rule give to me, the words in the item table should only be discarded if they are at the end and not followed by any other words, other that the one in the table..

Comment: I have a table of words that need to be removed from the given string if they are the last words.But if they appear in between other words they should not be discarded..

Comment: @showri in the first example why are the last two words removed instead of just the last one "LLC"? Add what the table of words would be for the given examples to your question.

Comment: the table contain two noise words:Company and LLC. if these noise words appear at the end of the string as in "American Company LLC", they should be removed(all the noise words),the expected output in this case is "American", but if the noise words appear in between other words like "American Company American Company LLC", the output for this should be "American Company American"--i am sorry the rule seems strange, but this is how it was written..

Comment: Based on your sample, you do not want to remove last word. You should be more specific and provides more details about requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
WITH 
DirtyValues AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
          (1, 'American Company, LLC') --Expected output --American (both noise words should be removed)
        , (2, 'American LLC,LLC') --Expected output -- American
        , (3, 'American Company American Company')-- American Company American (one noise word occurs in between other words, so it should not be removed)
    ) AS T(ID, Dirty)
),
NoisyWords AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
          (' ') -- Just apend the chars to be filtered to your noise word list
        , (',')
        , ('LLC')
        , ('Company')
    ) AS T(Noisy)
),
DoSomeMagic AS(
    SELECT ID
         , Result = REVERSE(Dirty)
    FROM DirtyValues 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID
         , Result = SUBSTRING(Result, DATALENGTH(Noisy)+1, DATALENGTH(Result))
    FROM DoSomeMagic
        CROSS APPLY(
            SELECT 
                  Noisy = REVERSE(Noisy)
            FROM NoisyWords
        ) AS T
    WHERE PATINDEX('%' + Noisy + '%', Result) = 1
),
PickBestResult AS(
    SELECT DoSomeMagic.ID
         , [clean as a whistle] = REVERSE(DoSomeMagic.Result)
         , [Rank]               = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATALENGTH(Result) ASC)
    FROM DoSomeMagic
)
SELECT *
FROM PickBestResult
WHERE [Rank] = 1
```

What it does:

- First 2 CTE's are your datasets, you'll of course want to change them for your own tables.
- DoSomeMagic is recursive CTE, first reversing the string to be able to seek from the end and then cross applies all the noise words and checks that the now start of the string starts with the reverse noise word. If so, remove it and keep on going until no noise words are found at the start.
- PickBestResult will then [Rank] each row and the own with shortest result will get Rank 1.